# Excluding current object from random suggestions

Tags: python, django

My current code as follow:

```
suggestions = Photo.objects.extra(where=['id!=%s'], params=[p.id]).order_by('?')[:10]
```

I was wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you could just use a basic [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude):

```
suggestions = Photo.objects.exclude(id=p.id).order_by('?')[:10]
```